# how can I use module variable as reference for inner class variable in Python?

Tags: python, variables, module

I would like to use a module variable as a globally accessible variable within a python program. Given that for a list the reference of that list will be retained in the variable, it would be possible (in theory) to have access to the updated content of the list at any time, and this is what i want actually in the end.

var_module.py:

```
my_var = None
```

var_reader.py:

```
from var_module import my_var

def f_read(pos):
    print("var: %s" % my_var[pos])
```

main.py:

```
import var_reader
# from var_module import my_var
import var_module

# my_var = var_module.my_var

class UpdateVar:
    def __init__(self):
        self.local_list = ["first"]

    def update_var(self):
        var_module.my_var = self.local_list

    def add_new_element_to_local_list(self):
        self.local_list.append("second")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    uvar = UpdateVar()
    uvar.update_var()
    var_reader.f_read(0)
    uvar.add_new_element_to_local_list()
    var_reader.f_read(1)
```

Also, instead of using "import var_reader", can "from var_module import my_var" be used?
In this case obviously there will be a shadowing issue of my_var inside the class method.

Thank you,

Comment: You *really* shouldn't be using global variables like this, it is bad design.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, any suggestions?

Comment: Anyway, you have to use `import var_module` in `var_reader.py`. When you do `from var_module import my_var`, it is basically creating *a new variable* where it is being imported. Now, since you initialize `var_module.my_var` to `None`, the reader sees `None`. Of course, if you initalized it as a list, then mutated that list, you would see those changes.

Comment: The thing is that I tried as a list too, but same issue: IndexError: list index out of range; what it is not accepting is the assignment var_module.my_var = self.local_list; If I do var_module.my_var.extend(self.local_list), it works, but I don't have the behavior I expect that being of retaining the reference of the self.local_list

Comment: You aren't making a lot of sense. You need to post a clear [mcve] and a clear problem description, don't put code in comments